# error install module with composer: PluginManager.php(273) : eval()'d code line 188

Tags: module, magento2.4, composer, composer-install

I have a problem when installing a module with composer, no matter which module, I get the same error. (*In PluginManager.php(273) : eval()'d code line 188*)

Magento v2.4, PHP 8.1

run

```
 composer require sendinblue/module-sendinblue
```

Result:

```
Using version ^2.1 for sendinblue/module-sendinblue
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update sendinblue/module-sendinblue
Loading composer repositories with package information
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking sendinblue/module-sendinblue (2.1.11)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading sendinblue/module-sendinblue (2.1.11)
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
  - Installing sendinblue/module-sendinblue (2.1.11): Extracting archive
Generating autoload files
121 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

In PluginManager.php(273) : eval()'d code line 188:
                                    
  chmod(): Operation not permitted
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is? Thanks very much

Comment: Please check the following thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975834/getting-chmod-operation-not-permitted-on-composer-update

Answer (score 1):

Just reset permission or try using : `sudo su`.